# Continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with fixed size finite fibers

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

During a business meeting, I was trying to find a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f^{-1}(\{y\})| = 2$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$, and after some experimentation I found $$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, \, x\mapsto \log(x^2).$$
For which integers $n>2$ is it possible to find a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f^{-1}(\{y\})| = n$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The function $f(x)=\log(x^2)$ which you suggested is undefined for $x=0$. (And I don't think it can be continuously extended.)

Comment: Can be done with fibers of size $1$ or $3$ or $5, \dots$

Comment: BTW a reformulation of this problem is that you want [Banach indicatrix](https://www.google.com/search?q=banach+indicatrix) to be constant and finite-valued.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, $x+\alpha_n \sin x$ will work for an appropriate $\alpha_n$. And this is not possible for $n$ even, by the intermediate value theorem. We necessarily have $f(x)\to \pm\infty$ as $x \to \pm\infty$ or $f(x)\to \mp\infty$ as $x \to \pm\infty$. Assume the former, and write $f^{-1}(a)=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. Then at least one of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is a (strict) local extremum. This means that $f$ has uncountably many strict local extrema, which is [not possible](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1545379/428180).

Comment: Apologies for this incredibly stupid non-example!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no continuous function $f:\,\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f^{-1}(x)|=2k$ for any $x$ (here $k$ is some fixed positive integer.)

Indeed, let $p_1<p_2<\ldots<p_{2k}$ be preimages of $0$. Fix small $\delta$ so that the $4k$ intervals $(p_i-\delta,p_i)$ and $(p_i,p_i+\delta)$ are mutually disjoint. Note that if $\varepsilon>0$ is small enough, then each of them contains a preimage either of $+\varepsilon$ or $-\varepsilon$. But $+\varepsilon$ and $-\varepsilon$ have $4k$ preimages in total, therefore exactly $2k$ intervals contain preimages of $+\varepsilon$ (call them ''positive'') and $2k$ intervals contain preimages of $-\varepsilon$ (call them ''negative''). Note that the intervals $(p_{i+1}-\delta,p_{i+1})$ and $(p_i,p_i+\delta)$ are simultaneously positive or simultaneously negative, since $f$ has constant sign on $(p_i,p_{i+1})$. Thus by parity of the number of positive intervals we conclude that the intervals $(p_1-\delta,p_1)$ and $(p_{2k},p_{2k}+\delta)$ also have the same sign. Since $f$ preserves the sign on the rays $(-\infty, p_1)$ and $(p_{2k},+\infty)$, we see that $f$ must have the same sign on these rays, and therefore $f$ is bounded either from above or from below. This contradicts to surjectivity.

Ah, I just realize that this is proved by Mateusz Kwaśnicki in the comments, but slightly differently (above reasoning does not use cardinality).